# How to collect a map key-value into a list

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Given the following map declaration

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map;
```

I want to collect all the keys and all the values together into a single `List<Integer>` using a single stream that iterates over the map's entries just once.

So far, I have only managed to do that using two separate stream iterations; one for the keys and one for the values.

Can it be done in one pass?

Comment: key-value pairs are available as a `Set<Entry<K, V>>` by `Map::entrySet`. `Set` is a `Collection`, so you can `stream` it, but you can also simply use `List::addAll` to add the content of the `Set` to a `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = map.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(...)` should do it for you. Each `Entry` has `getKey()` and `getValue()`, so you should be able to compose those into 2-length streams in the `flatMap` lambda, then just wrap it all up with a list collector.

Alternatively, look at using `.entrySet().reduce()` to build up a list element by element.

Comment: I don't see why you use flatMap here

Comment: @njzk2 My impression was that he wanted all of the keys AND all of the values in a single list, rather than combining them somehow (as you described.) As such, the mapping isn't one-to-one, so he'd want to use a flatMap.

Comment: @EdwardPeters your answer is correct but Bohemian gave a code example that works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function `Integer t(K key, V value)`,

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> t(entry.key, entry.value))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```